# High coordinates given by an api

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

in my Android app, I need to display some points on a map.
I get points coordinates from an API (http://data.citedia.com/r1/parks).

However, coordinated given by the API have high values : **"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-187178.15,6124340.9]}**.
I mean longitude is between -180 or 180...

Has anyone experienced the same issue ?

Comment: It is because coordinates are given in meters. The issue arises because Google creates the map in the 3857 projection system but then gives you coordinates in lat lon because it is easier to read and remember. Now I'm on mobile and can't give you the code, but if you search for "convert 3857 to 4326 epsg" you should fine tons of examples. Otherwise I will give you the code when I'll get back to my desktop.

Comment: Yes, i will appreciate some piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here it is how i did it:
download the JavaProj-noawt library (from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaproj106noawtjar.htm ) or any other source, it's a version suitable for android, which does not have awt classes.

then use the code below:

```
public static double[] convertFromWebMercatorToLatLng(double x, double y) {
    Projection googleProjection = getGoogleProjection();
    Point2D.Double latLngPoint = new Point2D.Double();
    latLngPoint = googleProjection.inverseTransform(new Point2D.Double(x, y), latLngPoint);
    return new double[] { latLngPoint.x, latLngPoint.y };
}

private static final int mGoogleEPSG = 3785;
// Projection EPSG
private static Projection mGoogleProjectionSystem = null;
private static Projection getGoogleProjection() {
    if (null == mGoogleProjectionSystem) {
        mGoogleProjectionSystem = ProjectionFactory.getNamedPROJ4CoordinateSystem("epsg:" + mGoogleEPSG);
    }
    return mGoogleProjectionSystem;
}
```

You just put this code in a "Util" class and the call it as a static method providing x(horizontal) and y(vertical) coordinates, will give you an array having in '0' the x (longitude) and in '1' latitude.

Be aware that LatLng object in google maps is "switched", containing (y,x) instead of (x,y) as in the methods above!